# Need some knowledge on Core Data - NSManagedObject usages

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, filtering

Just a quick question regarding loading data into the app through Core Data - I have already implemented Core Data and app is pretty much running just as it was before I started using it.

In short, when app launches I am fetching all the Entities into a Manager script that stores each object into different arrays and when the app uses the objects the Manager script will pass these arrays to other scripts.

My question is, does this seem like a bad method while using Core Data? Should I just be fetching the Entities when the scripts want them or its fine 'pre-fetching' from the start? This data is limited (to a point) and doesn't change during runtime.

Also, since I have all the entities in different arrays in the Manager script, I am sorting/filtering these arrays by predicates when a script needs something done. (which means I am never using a Core Data fetch with predicate since all the data is already available in the Manager's arrays)

App is already done, was just trying to make performance improvements and by adding Core Data, there is a huge boost. This is kind of my last question (at the moment) and I'm not really sure on the answer since I have never used Core Data before.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is fine.

There are three main drawbacks to prefetching:

1. You can take up too much memory and crash.
2. If an entity is deleted and you keep a pointer to it, the app will crash when you try to use that managedObject
3. Loading might take a very long time if there is a lot of data.

You said "This data is limited (to a point) and doesn't change during runtime" so it appears that none of these issue apply to you.

That being said I am not sure that you are really getting any benefit from core data in this setup.  Core data in general scales very well, but your setup will not.  You could just as easily store all your information in a file and load it all into memory when the app starts.  I trust that you getting other benefits from core data that are not stated in your question.